# parallel arrows in MathJax

Tags: commutative-diagrams, mathjax

How do I type 2 parallel arrows in MathJax ? And even in LaTeX ?
Without an enviroment. From object $A$ to an obeject $B$.

Comment: The resources identified here should always be consulted first when trying to identify a symbol: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This symbol?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\( A \rightrightarrows B \)
\end{document}
```

The same command works in MathJax.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\begin{document} 

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
$A\circlearrowleft B$  & $A\leftleftarrows B$      & $A\rightleftarrows B$     \\
$A\circlearrowright B$ & $A\leftrightarrows B$     & $A\rightrightarrows B$    \\
$A\curvearrowleft B$   & $A\leftrightsquigarrow B$ & $A\rightsquigarrow B$     \\
$A\curvearrowright B$  & $A\Lleftarrow B$          & $A\Rsh B$                 \\
$A\dashleftarrow B$    & $A\looparrowleft B$       & $A\twoheadleftarrow B$    \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A delay of 3 minutes to prepare this table.